# how to parse this (inner)xml?

Tags: powershell

i’m very new to powershell, and i’m abit stuck.

I have this innerXML:

```
    <sl-test.protocol>HTTP</sl-test.protocol>
    <sl-test.responseTimeout>14000</sl-test.responseTimeout>
    <env>${myenv}</env>
    <http.port>8081</http.port>
```

And i want to convert it into a .properties file in this format:

```
sl-test.protocol=HTTP
sl-test.responseTimeout=14000
env=${myenv}
http.port=8081
```

i have the part to create the .properties file (hardcoded value right now) which works:

```
    $test = New-Item -Name "mule-app.properties" -ItemType "file" -Value "test.prop=testprop`ntest2.prop=test2prop"
```

So basically i need to go from the innerXML to a big string of key/values separated by  `n
But also i need to escape any $ with a backtick

desired string:

```
    sl-test.protocol=HTTP`nsl-test.responseTimeout=14000`nenv`${myenv}`nhttp.port=8081
```

But right now i cant even seem to iterate through all the keys and values.

Note: the keys and values will be dynamic, it will not always be those 4

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The [`.ChildNodes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlNode.ChildNodes) property of the nodes in an `[xml]` ([`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument) instance allows you to loop over a given XML element's ([`System.Xml.XmlElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlElement)) child elements.

```bash
# Sample XML input.
[xml] $xml = @'
<el>
    <sl-test.protocol>HTTP</sl-test.protocol>
    <sl-test.responseTimeout>14000</sl-test.responseTimeout>
    <env>${myenv}</env>
    <http.port>8081</http.port>
</el>
'@

# Loop over all child elements of the document element.
$xml.el.ChildNodes |
  ForEach-Object {
    # Create and output a line for the output file, based on the 
    # element's name and inner text, with "$" escaped as "`$"
    '{0}={1}' -f $_.Name, $_.InnerText.Replace('$', '`$')
  } | # Set-Content out.properties -Encoding utf8
```

Uncomment and adapt the [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) call as needed.